# Correct usage of pd.insert() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am reading multiple .csv files and writing them to a new .csv file.

I am trying to use an if/else statement in conjunction with `pd.insert()` to add a new column to the beginning of a dataframe as such:

```
path = r'.../Model_AMs'

allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

for file_ in allFiles:

    df = pd.read_csv(file_, header=None).astype(int).transpose().melt()

    if 'slot' in file_:
        df.insert(loc=0, column='label', value=0)
        print('slot file!')
    else:
        df.insert(loc=0, column='label', value=1)
        print('boss file!')

    pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(df.index, df.value)), index=[0]).to_csv(
      'trainingdata.csv', index=False, header=None, mode='a')
```

Currently the new csv file looks something like this:

```
pixel0, pixel1, pixel2,...
0, 1, 1,...
```

I want it to look like this:

```
label, pixel0, pixel1, pixel2,...
1, 0, 1, 1,...
```

Writing the csv files is working as I want it to, however I want to add a new column to the beginning of each dataframe based on what the file name contains. Not sure if I am using the `pd.insert()` function correctly or maybe the if/else statement is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think you need change `pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(df.index, df.value)), index=[0])` to `df`

Answer (score 0):

Write your `df` directly:

```
df.to_csv('trainingdata.csv', header=None, index=False, mode='a')
```

no need to create another DataFrame.

Comment: That doesn't write the df to the new csv the way I want it to. Anyway writing the df isn't the problem, it's trying to insert a new column at the beginning of the df called 'label' which has a value of 1 or 0 depending on what the filename contains.

Comment: But you create a ne df before writing that obviously does not have the column you added anymore.

Comment: So do I need to add in a 'return df' at the end of the if/else statement to return the updated df? I tried doing that but got a syntax error and wasn't sure if it was right or not.